# How to remove gallery from Chrome App mediaGelleries list?

Tags: google-chrome-app

The list of potential mediaGalleries that appears when chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystems is interactive includes two entries that I'd like to get rid of: An empty entry that I don't know how got there, and a path that I added manually.

[image: Media galleries to choose from]

I can uncheck them -- my question is about to get them off the list entirely.

I've tried trashing and then re-installing the app, to no effect. I also tried chrome.mediaGalleries.dropPermissionForMediaFileSystem, but that effectively unchecks the gallery--it does not remove it from the list.